# Xero API authentication without OAuth2

Tags: php, laravel, xero-api

**The scenario**

So I am building an app that should display data from my [Xero](https://www.xero.com/) account to the users. Users should not be able to login via OAuth2 to my web app so that's why I need persistent auth token that is independent from the users login. The current API authentication implementation from Xero does not allow that and the token expires in 30 minutes so I need a way to do this somehow in the background or with any kind of persistent token (which is not available as I can see in their [docs for Auth](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/overview))

**Stack**

I am using **Laravel** with the package [Xero Laravel](https://github.com/langleyfoxall/xero-laravel) and this one's using the [XeroPHP](https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php) package in its core as dependency. Currently I am using Postman to do refresh token requests and I am adding the token manually (for testing purposes of course). This should not be the case when it goes on production, though. So I need a way to somehow "store" or refresh the token globally for the whole app and using only my account as an Authorization to Xero.

**Problem summary**

My web app need to fetch data (invoices data in particular) from **my** Xero account and no OAuth tokenization is required for the users (since I am using the native Laravel Auth for this purpos) that are going to read this data in a GUI.

How should I accomplish this without OAuth2 (if there is any way) or how I can do this if only my account is the "global" one for the app?

Comment: My understanding is that you cannot do it without OAuth2 now. But you can generate the Access Token and Refresh token with only a single instance of user interaction (which you could do yourself) and then keep refreshing after the token expires. See this video for an idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcf_64yreVI&t=1s when using machine to machine connections.

Comment: @droopsnoot thanks for this manual. I already set this up but I was wondering what's the best way to store the access_tokens on Laravel (PHP) side after they are refreshed. I was thinking about Redis (in memory db caching) but not sure if that's the best idea...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I know a bit of PHP but have no experience with stuff like Laravel (I've heard of it, but no idea what it actually is / does). In VB I just store them in the application settings file, or a text file would do just as well.

Answer (score 1):

The other comments are correct that there is an initial required step to have the user that you are calling API endpoints on behalf of to authorize your API application.

---

Once you have their valid token_set ( access_token, refresh_token, expiry, etc.. ) you can store that securely and continue making offline_access api calls on their behalf. *Note* that you must programmatically refresh the token_set at least once every 60 days for it to remain valid.

I'd also recommend checking out the Xero supported libraries for help getting started quickly:

- https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2
- https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2-starter

Thanks to @droopsnoot for linking the video explaining how this works:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcf_64yreVI

Comment: The video link is not available anymore ;(

Comment: You should be able to get in touch with Dev Relations team via https://developer.xero.com/